# sending datatable value to another form and create a loop and shown it in dgv

Tags: c#, gridview, datatable

i have one form in which I create a datable globally. in datatable data is save dynamically. when every I press add button to save the data , a popup screen shown. at that screen i have a grid view in which i want to loop over some data and show it in that table....
all i need to know that how can i get the value from datable and create a loop  and show data in data grid view

```
 register form = new register();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt=form.purchasedtable;
           int  frooms=int.Parse(dt.Columns["Froms"].ToString());
            string to = dt.Columns["To"].ToString();
            for (int i =frooms; i <= int.Parse(to); i++)
            {
                DataTable dtt = new DataTable();

                dataGridView2.Rows.Add(dtt);
            }
```

this is what i did but this is not working

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Winforms

```
    var dataTable = new DataTable();

                // Get All Rows
                var rows = dataTable.Rows;
// Loop Over all rows                
foreach (DataRow dataRow in rows)
                {
                    //Get All Columns in Rows
                    var rowArray = dataRow.ItemArray;

foreach (var col in rowArray)
                    {
                        if (col is int)
                        {
                            var number = (int) col;
                            Console.WriteLine(number.ToString());
                        }
                        if (col is string)
                        {
                            var number = (string) col;
                            Console.WriteLine(number.ToString());
                        }
                        if (col is double)
                        {
                            var number = (double) col;
                            Console.WriteLine(number.ToString());
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: Okay the given code can give the table values
After clicking the button pass the values in the constructor of the form

Like `new MyForm(rowValues);`